# Trying to make method print

Tags: java

I am trying to sort numbers into two categories. Number (actual number) and count (how many occurrences of this number), all of the numbers are stored in a array of 50 integers. I sort this array in descending order using a bubble sort method.

My print method needs work. The code compiles just fine but when I run the code nothing is output.

Why is my code not printing anything?

Here is my code

```
public class HW5{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[50];
        bubbleSort(array, 'D');
        printArray(array);
    }
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array, char d){
        int r = (d=='D') ? -1 : 1 ;
        for (int f = 0; f < array.length - 1; f ++){ 
            for (int index = 0; index < array.length - 1; index++){    
                if (array[index] > array[index + 1]){       

                }
            }        
        }
    }
    public static void printArray(int[] array){
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
            if (array[i]== array[i + 1]){
                count = count + 1;
            }else{
                System.out.printf(count + "/t" + array[i]);
                count = 0;
            }   
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Your array is initialized such that all of the elements are `0`. Your code for printing never finds any unequal values, so the `else` never executes.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why is my code not printing anything?*

object **array** is holding 50 elements all of them with the value set to zero and the **printArray** method will print if and only IF this condition is false

```
array[i] != array[i + 1]
```

but since all elements in the array are 0... you just dont print anything...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing anything because you aren't setting your array values to anything. Because you aren't setting your array to anything, java defaults all the values to 0. Your code doesn't output if `array[i] == array[i+1]` I'd change your print method to this:

```
public static void printArray(int[] array){
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        if (array[i]== array[i + 1]){
            count = count + 1;
        }else{
            System.out.print(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(array[i]); //Moved this line out of the if/else statement so it will always print the array at i   
    }
}
```

I only changed the line I commented on. However, if you did change the values of your array, your original code would work. For random values, first you need to import `java.util.Math` then do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = (int)Math.random() * 100; //Sets the array at i to a random number between 0 and 100 (non-inclusive)
```

This will help your code above to work as you wanted. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Fixed a grammar error.